# other results when declaring in main method vs. outside from main method

Tags: c++, arrays, program-entry-point

I am currently doing a simple problem on [codeforce](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/A).
Basically you are given a string (e.g. "1+3+2") and you have to return it sorted (e.g. "1+2+3"). Only 1,2 and 3 will be used.

I started with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    string str;
    int arr[4];
    cin >>str;    

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length();i+=2)
        arr[str[i] - '0']++;    
}
```

My idea was to store every occurrence of a number in an array. But I noticed a problem if I would add

```
cout<< arr[2];
```

and input "1+2+3", it outputs:

> 33

However, it should be 1, because 3 only occurred once.

I solved it, by moving "string str;" and "int arr[4]" up, over main:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string str;
int arr[4];

int main()
{   
    cin >>str;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length();i+=2)
        arr[str[i] - '0']++;
    cout<< arr[2];
}
```

Output:

> 1

Why does it work now?

Comment: You should check variables initialization. By defaults,`int` contains garbage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Automatic storage duration with no initializer: default initialization applies: an array of fundamental non-class type will remain with uninitialized values

In your first example, `arr` has automatic storage duration and is uninitialized, as a result of default initialization:

```
int main() {
    // default initialization
    int arr[4];

    // reading from arr at this point (remains
    // uninitialized) is undefined behaviour.
}
```

The effect of default initialization of an array type is that every element of the array is default-initialized. The effect of default initialization on fundamental non-class types is nothing: the elements will remain uninitialized. Reading from such elements (invocation of `operator++` upon the elements in your example) is undefined behaviour.

You can e.g. value-initialize `arr` using the following syntax:

```
int main() {
    int arr[4]{};
}
```

with the effect that each element of the array is value-initialized, which in turn has the effect that each element of the array (fundamental non-class type) is zero-initialized.

---

#### Static storage duration: zero-initialization applies

In the second example, `arr` no longer has automatic storage duration but static storage duration, and the rules of static initialization applies, which will lead to `arr` being zero-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialise `int arr[4];` in your first example. **As such the behaviour of your program is undefined.**

If you print the contents of `arr` without your first for loop:

```
for (auto x: arr) {
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

You get garbage data that happens to be sitting at the address of `arr`:

```
121
32584
615125669
22063
```

But you are not guaranteed to get anything. If you provide the compiler with an invalid program it is allowed to do whatever it pleases.

---

You can **fix** this by initialising your array:

```
int arr[4] = {};
```

This will value initialise the array, which for `int` means initialisation with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not initialize arrays to 0 by default. You initial content is unpredictable, same about your results.

There are multiple ways to resolve the problem. I would suggest to use [std::vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-16-an-introduction-to-stdvector/), declaring the variable like:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> arr(4, 0);
```

The first parameter is the size, the second is the initial value for all elements (0 is default). You can just use it as an array with []. It has other useful features, can grow for instance if needed.

Alternatively, you can also use  [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) to clear the array:

```
#include <cstring>
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
```

This function is older and you need more care with it.